# Finding joint probability from double marginals

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, probability-distributions

Consider three probability distributions in the form $p_1(y,z),p_2(x,z),p_3(x,y)$.

When does a global joint probability $p(x,y,z)$ (possibly not unique) exist?

The first compatibility condition to check is of course that the first order marginals check out: $p_2(x)=p_3(x)$, and so on.
Is this the only condition, is it necessary and sufficient?

Thanks!

Comment: note: cross-posted to MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201485/finding-joint-probability-from-double-marginals